# SQL server JOIN query not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I have doubt in sql server

**dept**

```
+---------+--------+
| deptkey | deptno |
+---------+--------+
|    1    |  100   |
|    2    |  101   |
|    3    |  -1    |
+---------+--------+
```

**loc**

```
+--------+-------+
| lockey | locid |
+--------+-------+
|   1    |  200  |
|   2    |  201  |
|   3    |  -1   |
+--------+-------+
```

**trans**

```
+----+--------+-------+------+
| id | deptno | locid | Name |
+----+--------+-------+------+
| 1  |  100   |  201  | abc  |
| 2  |  101   |  203  | def  |
| 3  |  103   |  200  | rav  |
| 4  |  105   |  204  | jai  |
| 1  |  101   |  200  | kal  |
| 4  |  100   |  206  | lo   |
+----+--------+-------+------+
```

here tran deptno= dept.deptno then corresponding key values bring if not match then we need to unmatched deptno assign -1 and corresponding key need to retrive
similar tran locid=loc.locid

based on above tables I want output like below

```
+----+------+---------+--------+
| id | Name | deptkey | lockey |
+----+------+---------+--------+
| 1  | abc  |    1    |   2    |
| 2  | def  |    2    |   3    |
| 3  | rav  |    3    |   1    |
| 4  | jai  |    3    |   3    |
| 1  | kal  |    2    |   1    |
| 4  | lo   |    1    |   3    |
+----+------+---------+--------+
```

I tried like below query

```
SELECT a.[id],a.name ,b.deptkey,c.lockey
  FROM [trans] a  left join dept b on a.deptno=b.deptno 
  left join  loc c on a.locid=c.locid
```

above query not given expected result can you please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Comment: What is your current output?  The query looks OK to me.

Comment: Here  tran table   id : 2   |  101     |  203     |def when we join with loc table loc id :203 not avilable in loc table that time we need unmatched records assign with -1 values and get corresponding key in final result.when I ran above query that time few off deptnos and locid  came null values but need only keys in final result

Comment: So are you saying that you don't want null values appearing in your final result?

Comment: yes.which are having null values we need to assign -1 and corresponding key values we need  retrieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT a.[id],a.name ,
    (CASE WHEN b.deptkey IS NULL THEN (select deptkey from DEPT WHERE DeptNo = -1) 
       ELSE b.deptkey END) AS 'deptkey',
    (CASE WHEN c.lockey IS NULL THEN (select LocKey from LOC WHERE LocId = -1) 
       ELSE c.lockey END) AS 'lockey '
 FROM [trans] a  left join dept b on a.deptno=b.deptno 
 left join  loc c on a.locid=c.locid
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/389463/2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.[id],a.name ,b.deptkey,c.lockey 

FROM [trans] a  left join dept b on isnull(a.deptno,-1)=isnull(b.deptno,-1) 
  left join  loc c on a.locid=c.locid
```

try with this...

Comment: query not given expected result.above mention query given query given same result only.here this condition will not  work isnull(a.deptno,-1)=isnull(b.deptno,-1)  reason is we donot know which trans records is not matched in dept and loc table records .when not matched that time -1 corresponding keys need to retrieve in final thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   a.[id]
   , a.name 
   , ISNULL(b.deptkey,-1) AS [deptkey]
   , ISNULL(b.lockey,-1) AS [lockey]
  FROM [trans] a  
  left join dept b 
      on a.deptno = b.deptno 
  left join  loc c 
      on a.locid = c.locid
```

When the value is not found `ISNULL`, change the result to `-1` instead of `NULL`. You can just change the `-1` with any `default value` you prefer as unmatched.

OR if you want a query driven default value (get the last record as the default value). You can change your script as presented below.

```
SELECT 
   a.[id]
   , a.name 
   , ISNULL(b.deptkey,(SELECT TOP 1 deptno from dept ORDER BY deptkey DESC)) AS [deptkey]
   , ISNULL(b.lockey,(SELECT TOP 1 locid from loc ORDER BY lockey DESC)) AS [lockey]
  FROM [trans] a  
  left join dept b 
      on a.deptno = b.deptno 
  left join  loc c 
      on a.locid = c.locid
```